# Offset wrong position

Tags: jquery, tooltip, offset

I want to add a tooltip with dinamic position change. This is js code:

```
$('a[rel=tooltip]').mouseover(function(e) {
        //Grab the title attribute's value and assign it to a variable
        var tip = $(this).attr('title');    
        //Remove the title attribute's to avoid the native tooltip from the browser
        $(this).attr('title','');   
        //Append the tooltip template and its value
        $(this).append('<div id="tooltip"><div class="tipHeader"></div><div class="tipBody">' + tip + '</div></div>');//Show the tooltip with faceIn effect
        $('#tooltip').fadeIn('500');
        $('#tooltip').fadeTo('10',0.9);
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        //Keep changing the X and Y axis for the tooltip, thus, the tooltip move along with the mouse
        $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 10 );
        $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 20 );
    }).mouseout(function() {
        //Put back the title attribute's value
        $(this).attr('title',$('.tipBody').html());
        //Remove the appended tooltip template
        $(this).children('div#tooltip').remove();
    });
```

My page: http://pododezhdoy.ru/catalog/women/nizhnee_bele/

**Problem:** Why script determine wrong postion?

Comment: Try adding $('#tooltip').css('position', 'absolute');.

Comment: Where do you want to position your tooltip ?

Comment: Odd. I've poked around as much as I can on the site, but nothing is obviously wrong there. On a hunch, try appending the tooltip to the body of the document rather than the target div...

Comment: If you want to put it under the pic remove this line: $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 20 );

Comment: Other problem, your're trying to overlay a div with overflow set to hidden, so when your tooltip appear over this div it will desapear.
If you remove it's property you'll se other mistakes.
Div.bx-window (Div with overflow)

Comment: I want to put tooltim under the mouse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What position should be right? This a code shows the tooltip above the image.

```
    var itempos = $(this).parent().position();
    $('#tooltip').css('top', itempos.top + 'px' );
    $('#tooltip').css('left', itempos.left + 'px' );
```

Comment: I want to put tooltim under the mouse.

Comment: You wanna fix coding errors first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpododezhdoy.ru%2Fcatalog%2Fwomen%2Fnizhnee_bele%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0